# How to properly re-render functional component after API call

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

When the page loads, I am making an API call, displaying a table with appointments. After the API call, I set a state for hasData to true, and the data is inserted in another setState. The issue is when the API returns the data from the async call, the component does not show the data.  Please see code below.

```
 const [recentAppointmentData, setRecentAppointmentData] = useState([])
 const [hasAppointmentData, setHasAppointmentData] = useState(false)

const getAppointments = useCallback(() => {
  const getAppointmentDataService = new GetAppointmentsService();

  getAppointmentDataService.getDataFromService("263749804").then((results) => {
    console.log("APPOINTMENT DATA ", results);

    results.recentAppointments.map((result) => {
      var recentAppointments = {
        appointmentObject: {
          serviceCategory: [],
          serviceId: "",
          appointmentDate: "",
          groomer: "",
          resourceId: "",
          visitId: "",
        },
      };
      if (result["services"] !== undefined) {
        console.log("SERVICESS", result["services"]);
        result["services"].map((service) => {
          recentAppointments.appointmentObject.serviceCategory.push(
            service["serviceCategory"]
          );
          recentAppointments.appointmentObject.serviceId = service["serviceId"];
        });
      }

      recentAppointments.appointmentObject.appointmentDate = moment(
        result["appointmentDateTime"]
      ).format("MM/DD/YY");
      recentAppointments.appointmentObject.groomer = result["groomer"];

      recentAppointments.appointmentObject.resourceId = result["resourceId"];
      recentAppointments.appointmentObject.visitId = result["visitId"];

      appointments.push(recentAppointments.appointmentObject);
```

Here I am setting the has Appointment data to true after the async function has been completed.

```
  if (!hasAppointmentData) {
    setHasAppointmentData(true);
  }
});
```

Here I am storing the data in another state.

```
    if (!hasAppointmentData) {
      console.log("APPOINTMEN", appointments);
      setRecentAppointmentData(appointments);
    }
  });
}, [hasAppointmentData]);
```

I am calling the function in the `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getAppointments();
  renderTabs();
}, [getAppointments, renderTabs]);
```

Can someone guide me on what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Reloading a page means "throwing the current website away, and loading a completely new website", you just happen to load the same URL. If you need data to persist across that action, use either sessionStorage (for storing data tied to a single tab, which you probably want here) or localStorage (for storing data per origin across any number of tabs). See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) for more information on both of those.

Comment: *"when the API finishes [...] the component does not show the data"* - Can you simplify the code into a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates?  If you're updating state then that certainly should trigger a re-render of the component.  But we don't know if your component is meaningfully "showing" that state in its render, or if it's showing something else.  When you debug the logic shown here, are the state setter calls (which are inside of conditional statements) even reached?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the `useEffect` hook wrong.

`useEffect` runs every time one of its dependencies change, or runs just once when the component mounts if you don't pass in any dependency to it. The dependencies are usually state variables within the component that `useEffect` runs in.

You want your `getAppointments()` to run only once, since it calls an external API to get the data. And you want to call `renderTabs()` (which I assume is responsible for displaying the data in the UI) only when the data is available. So you need to put them into two separate `useEffect` hooks.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getAppointments();
}, []);    // Runs just once when the component is mounted

useEffect(() => {
  if (hasAppointmentData) {
    renderTabs();
  }
}, [hasAppointmentData]);    // Runs every time the value of hasAppointmentData changes
```

But you'll need to watch out for a problem here, when using `hasAppointmentData` as the dependency. You're calling `setHasAppointmentData` first, and then following it up with `setRecentAppointmentData`. The second `useEffect` hook would run right after you set the boolean to `true`. By the time `renderTabs()` tries to fetch the data from `recentAppointmentData`, the data may not have been updated.

To me, `hasAppointmentData` is pretty much useless here. Checking for `recentAppointmentData.length` would serve you just as well, and is guaranteed to work reliably every time. So my second hook would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (recentAppointmentData.length) {
    renderTabs();
  }
}, [recentAppointmentData.length]);
```